# To path the parameter to OAuth facebook login by symfony2/HWIOAuthBundle

Tags: facebook, symfony, oauth, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle

This question is related to this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29646646/how-can-i-use-two-defferent-aouth-registration-pages)

I have googled many times and made the problem more precisely.

My question is very simple.

Can I pass the parameter from here (for example : myStatus=1)

```
<a href="{{ path('hwi_oauth_service_redirect', { 'service' : 'facebook' }) }}" />facebook</a>
```

to this class?

FOSUBUserProvider class MyUserBundle\Security\Core\User

```
class FOSUBUserProvider extends BaseClass
{ 
    protected $container;
    public function __construct(UserManagerInterface $userManager, $container, array $properties)     
    {
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->properties  = $properties;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function connect(UserInterface $user, UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $property = $this->getProperty($response);
        $username = $response->getUsername();

         //I WANT TO USE THE myStatus PARAMTER HERE!!!

        //on connect - get the access token and the user ID
        $service = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();

        $setter = 'set'.ucfirst($service);
        $setter_id = $setter.'Id';
        $setter_token = $setter.'AccessToken';

        //we "disconnect" previously connected users
        if (null !== $previousUser = $this->userManager->findUserBy(array($property => $username))) {
            $previousUser->$setter_id(null);
            $previousUser->$setter_token(null);
            $this->userManager->updateUser($previousUser);
        }
        //we connect current user
        $user->$setter_id($username);
        $user->$setter_token($response->getAccessToken());

        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $username = $response->getUsername();
        $user_details= $response->getResponse();
        $user = $this->userManager->findUserBy(array('email' => $user_details['email']));

          //when the user is registering
        if (null === $user) {
            $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();

            $service = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();
            $setter = 'set'.ucfirst($service);
            $setter_id = $setter.'Id';
            $setter_token = $setter.'AccessToken';
            // create new user here
            $user = $this->userManager->createUser();
            $user->$setter_id($username);
            $user->$setter_token($response->getAccessToken());
            //I have set all requested data with the user's username
            //modify here with relevant data
            $avatar   = $response->getProfilePicture();

            $user->setUsername($username);
            $user->setFirstName($user_details['first_name']);
            $user->setLastName($user_details['last_name']);
            $user->setUserKey($this->generateRandomString());
            $user->setEmail($user_details['email']);      
            $user->setPassword($this->generateRandomString());
            $user->setEnabled(true);
            $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
            return $user;
        }

        $serviceName = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();
        $setter = 'set' . ucfirst($serviceName) . 'AccessToken';

        //update access token
        $user->$setter($response->getAccessToken());

        return $user;
    }
```

in my config.yml

```
hwi_oauth:
    # name of the firewall in which this bundle is active, this setting MUST be set
    connect:
        account_connector: my_user_provider
    fosub:
        username_iterations: 30
        properties:
            # these properties will be used/redefined later in the custom FOSUBUserProvider service.
            facebook: facebook_id
    firewall_name: main
    resource_owners:
        facebook:
            type:                facebook
            client_id:           ******
            client_secret:       *******
            scope:               "email,public_profile"
            options:
                display: popup
```

my services.xml

```
   <services>
     <service id="my_user_provider" class="Acme\UserBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider">
        <argument type="service" id="fos_user.user_manager"/>
        <argument type="service" id="service_container" />

        <argument type="collection">
            <argument key="facebook">facebook_id</argument>
            <argument key="google">google_id</argument>
            <argument key="twitter">twitter_id</argument>
        </argument>

    </service>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never worked with HWIOAuthBundle but I assume that you're injecting service  container with `$container` argument. So, we have an access to service container we can simply access to `request_stack` service with it and get query string paramters from it..

example:

```
<a href="{{ path('hwi_oauth_service_redirect', { 'service' : 'facebook', 'myStatus':1 }) }}" />facebook</a>
```

connect method:

```
public function connect(UserInterface $user, UserResponseInterface $response)
{
     $property = $this->getProperty($response);
     $username = $response->getUsername();

     $request = $this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();

     $myStatus = $request->query->get('myStatus');
```

Comment: Thanks xurshid29. I have tried this way , but still $myStatus is null. I guess the argument 'service' 'myStatus' are not sent to connect method directly.Since it is redirected to FOSUBUserProvider class via some where.

Comment: url written in twig is shown like this in html .<a href="/myApp/web/app_dev.php/login/facebook?myStatus=1" />

Comment: @whitebear Try to print `request_stack` object (`var_dump($this->container->get('request_stack'))` or use `dump` method), I'm sure there'll be something in the stack..

Comment: Hi @xurshid29 I can't find something related with myStatus though, Instead I use referer to accomplish my purpose.