# Pass parameter HWIOAuthbundle symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, hwioauthbundle

I'm trying to pass a GET parameter from my Facebook and Google login button, that I've set up using HWIOAuthbundle. I've looked at this question: [To path the parameter to OAuth facebook login by symfony2/HWIOAuthBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30294363/to-path-the-parameter-to-oauth-facebook-login-by-symfony2-hwioauthbundle), however I didn't quite understand how he managed to get it working. He mentions using referer, which I don't anything about - and I don't have enough reputation to post a comment on that question...

I was thinking something like this:

```
<a href="{{ path('google_login',{'datakey':1}) }}">Link</a>
```

But how do I retrieve it in my FOSUBUserProvider?
I appreciate all help!

Comment: have you tried something like `<a href="{{ path('google_login') }}?datakey=1">Link</a>`?

Comment: Hi Matteo, I ended up making a cookie instead, and getting it in my FOSUBUserProvider :) Thx for answer anyway!

Comment: Hi @Mathias, you are welcome! Seem interesting, can you describe your solution as answer to this question? So you can also close as resolved and help other on related problem

Comment: Hi Matteo, check answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get it working. However, I am not sure it is the best way to do it. It's a quick fix until I find a more proper solution.

When someone enters my website with the datakey variable as a $_GET parameter, I set a cookie with the value. When the user logs in, the FOSUBUserProvider checks whether the datakey cookie is set; if it is, it will do its thing.

This is the best I can do for now, as I haven't managed to succeed sending parameters through the hwioauthbundle and into my FOSUBUserProvider.

If someone finds a better solution, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

No need to set a cookie. Just set a session variable first (in controller):

```
$session->set('role', 'ROLE_CLIENT');
```

Then, inject the session in your UserProvider (in services.yaml):

```
app.user.oauth_provider:
  class:     App\Security\Core\User\AppUserProvider
  arguments: ['@doctrine', { google: googleId, facebook: facebookId, apple: appleId }, '@session']
  public:    true
```

Finally, get the variable in your UserProvider, use it, and then clear it:

```
$role = $this->session->get('role');
if ($role) {
  $user->addRole($role);
  $this->session->set('role', null);
}
```